# Can I setup RavenDB on Windows to version/manage large binary files?

Tags: version-control, ravendb, asset-management, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to version control my system deployment bits: OS images, drivers, 3rd party installers, 1st party installers (our applications). I need to have everything in a coherent bundle (tags). And be able to get the entire bundle for any of our active releases. 
I'm finding that no common version control system is going to fit the bill. And even the ones that have [some capabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033030/are-there-tools-for-managing-large-binary-files-in-git-on-windows) ([git media, annex, bup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540535/managing-large-binary-files-with-git)) will not run well on Windows. Digital Asset Management systems seem not entirely suited for this purpose and are very foreign to me.

I heard that people are building custom systems on document databases like MongoDB. I'm asking you for advice on how to build, structure, and maintain a system like this on RavenDB and the Windows server/client platform.

Comment: This sounds interesting. Do you have some links explaining more details about what you want to build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not prepared to build a custom RavenDB app/instance for this purpose. After a lot of experimentation, I've settled on [NuGet](http://nuget.org/) and [Chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/), along with the original large binary data store, a network drive!

Answer (score 3):

RavenDB has specific support for binary attachments, which is handled in an efficient manner.
You can handle things that way.